# What is the usage of parentheses for strings when calling binding methods in Lua ？

Tags: lua

I am a beginner of `Lua`, and I was confused with the usage of `()`.

Here are some examples on `Lua5.3`.

```
a = '%s %s'
a:format("Hello", "World")             -- Hello World
'%s %s':format("Hello", "World")       -- stdin:1: unexpected symbol near ''%s %s''
('%s %s'):format("Hello", "World")     -- Hello World

type(a) == type('%s %s')               -- true
getmetatable(a)                        -- table: 0x1f20bf0
getmetatable('%s %s')                  -- table: 0x1f20bf0 for any other hard coded strings
```

Question:

1. What did the `()` do to the hard coded string?
2. Otherwise, only syntax error? :D

Comment: They're all hard-coded strings, which one is confusing you? That's just how you make a function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mandatory usage of parenthesis (or a variable) in the first example with the function call is due to Lua grammar rules: this is simply how the language grammar is defined, and not following the defined grammar results in syntax/parse errors.

See [Section 2.5.8 – Function Calls, of the Lua Reference](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8).

> A function call in Lua has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> functioncall ::= prefixexp args
> ```
>
> In a function call, first prefixexp and args are evaluated. If the value of prefixexp has type function, then this function is called with the given arguments. Otherwise, the prefixexp "call" metamethod is called, having as first parameter the value of prefixexp, followed by the original call arguments (see §2.8).
>
> The form
>
> ```
> functioncall ::= prefixexp `:´ Name args
> ```
>
> ..

Where [`prefixexp` is defined](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#8) as:

> ```
> prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | ( exp )
> ```

That is, `prefixexp` *cannot* be a `String` (or any other) literal, but it *can* be a variable (`var`); or any expression *inside parentheses* (`( expr )`); or even chained function call (`functioncall`)..

Using a `String` (or any other) literal in the `args` position is permitted due to the following productions:

> ```
> args ::=  `(´ [explist] `)´ | tableconstructor | String
> explist ::= {exp `,´} exp
> ```

As a complimentary case to the examples, note that the `args` production has a special-case that *doesn't* require parenthesis if taking a *single* `String` literal. Thus the following is valid, even if seemingly odd:

```
('Hello %s'):format "World!"
```

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question.
I decided to read the chapter 2 of the manual.